# How to create custom email address on user signup PHP or Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, email, server

I am working on a project that requires a user to have a custom email on register, send and receive email with their custom email within the application and I will need ideas on which server to host the application.

Currently am developing the application in PHP using Laravel framework and I am thinking of hosting the app on Fortrabbit or Heroku.

I will really appreciate your support.

Comment: Do you mean hosting a new email address when user signs up? Can I assume your server will handle incoming & outgoing emails? If you're using IMAP, you can make use of `imap_createmailbox()` function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-createmailbox.php

Comment: imap-createmailbox creates folders and all i want is for the user to have an email account on registering on my platform for example on signup the user gets rocky@mydomain.com as an email to be used to communicate within the app.

Comment: I misunderstood your question. You have to know which email server you're using first, before you want to do next. If cPanel is installed, there are PHP scripts to create email accounts via PHP. See [this](http://www.zubrag.com/scripts/cpanel-create-email-account.php)

Comment: Thanks @Raptor but what if i want to use a PaaS hosting like Heroku or Fortrabbit, how can i still achieve it or do you know of any mail server i can use that can communicate with heroku and still give me the same result?