# Create new email after user registration

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8, email

i have existing implementation of Laravel's make:auth authentication system. What i need now is the following: my domain is example.com . when a new user registers, lets call him testuser , after registration to be created a new email like: testuser@example.com .

there was a question here like 3 years ago, ( [How to create custom email address on user signup PHP or Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38845366/how-to-create-custom-email-address-on-user-signup-php-or-laravel) ) and it was suggested to be used createmailbox, but it only creates imap folders and not new email addresses. one of the options (havent dug deep into it) is using cpanel and their api to create new email accounts, but havent tried it as now i dont have access to the domain where the project will be hosted. 
if anyone has any suggestions or examples, please share them